# Render columns using twitter's bootstrap and Rails4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm building a prototype using Rails4. I made the following `custom.css.scss`:

```
// System wide CSS

html {
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 2px;
  height: auto;
}

body {
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
}

img {
    align: left;
    border: 2px white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.profile_image {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.col1of3,  .col2of3, .col3of3 {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

My problem is how columns are displayed. In this view fine because I don't use `columns`: [image: good views]

But this page, where I use `columns` the body element seems to be shorter and the length element larger: [image: bad views]
<sub>(source: [screensteps.me](http://media.screensteps.me/atmosx/ycqaqc/css3-problem.png?1399409643))</sub>

I know the problem is related with related to views. So here are my `edit.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Προσθήκη Ασθενούς</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Πίσω', patients_path %>
```

And this is my `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@patient) do |f| %>
  <% if @patient.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>Σφάλμα κατά την διαδικασία αποθήκευσης: </h2>

      <ul>
      <% @patient.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="col1of3">
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Όνομα" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Επώνυμο" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :surname %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Φύλο" %><br>
      <%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(list_genders)%>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Ημερομηνία Γεννήσεως" %><br>
      <%= f.date_select :birthday, :start_year => 1920, :use_month_names => ['Ιανούριος', 'Φεβρουάριος', 'Μάρτιος', 'Απρίλιο', 'Μάιος', 'Ιούνιος', 'Ιούλιος', 'Αύγουστος', 'Σεπτέμβριος', 'Οκτώβριος', 'Νοέμβριος','Δεκέμβριος'] %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Εικόνα" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :image_url %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "ΑΜΚΑ" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :social_security_number %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col2of3">
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Οργανισμός Ασφάλισης" %><br>
      <%= f.select :social_security_institution, options_for_select(list_greek_sso) %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Αρ Οργαν Ασφάλισης" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :social_security_institution_number %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "ΑΦΜ" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :afm %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Τηλ οικίας" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :home_phone %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Τηλ εργασίας" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :work_phone %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Κινητό" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :mobile_phone %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Πατρώνυμο (του)" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :father_name %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col3of3">
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Διεύθυνση Οικίας" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :home_address %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Πόλη" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :city %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Χώρα" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :country, :value => 'Ελλάδα' %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Ταχυδρομικός Κώδικας" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :postal_code %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label :email %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <%= f.label "Σημειώσεις" %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :notes, cols: "50", rows: "8" %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Υποβολή" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any idea why the element of columns acts like if it's outside the `<body>` tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of the float property. At the very end of your _form.html.erb, consider inserting the following right before `<% end %>` -

```
<div style="clear: both;"/>
```

Does that clear it up?

Comment: No problem! I'm not sure I'll do a good job of explaining, but think of float as not being able to give the body information about its div's height. You need either an extra div at the bottom to clear it, or a non-floated container div of the three columns (which, it doesn't look like you have).